# Strategy for loading data into a class and using it

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, subclass, appdelegate

Assuming I have a class which loads my initial data set

```
//  DataModel.m


#import "DataModel.h"
@implementation DataModel
@synthesize items;

-(id) init{
    self  = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self loadData];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadData
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dataFile" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (!jsonString) {
        NSLog(@"File couldn't be read!");
        return;
    }
    // json was loaded, carry on
    DLog(@"json Data loaded from file");
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error){
        DLog(@"ERROR with json: %@",error);
        return;
    }

    items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"items"];

}
```

I am initialising it (once) in my appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    appDataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    DLog(@"init %@",appDataModel);

    return YES;
}
```

This dataset is about to be used and manipulated throughout the app - at the end it will be saved , replacing the original ("dataFile.json")

**QUESTION:**
What is the best strategy to do so? (going to use this dataset in many viewcontrollers...)
The Dataset is relevantly small but I rather keep it in a single place AND in memory while manipulating / reading it.

Q2 - should I really init it (once) in the appDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

> It’s an extremely powerful way to share data between different parts of code without having to pass the data around manually.

Comment: thanks, Q2 - should I really init it (once) in the appDelegate?

Comment: If you follow the link, you not need to init it anywhere. When sharedInstance is called for the first time the object will be initialized, the following sharedInstance calls, will return the object already initialized.